# Do we have an option to see the Apex code or Apex Trigger for Managed Type Package in Enterprise Edition

Tags: apex, trigger, managed-package

Can any one let me know whether we do have an option to check the apex code or apex trigger written for Managed Type package in Enterprise edition.My client uses an third party app (i.e. Email to Case Premium app) in an enterprises edition ,where im unable to see the trigger written.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Curious why you want to see the code. Is there something you hope to find in it, or some piece of information you need?

Answer (score 1):

Since our AppExchange partners are selling apps, they are allowed to protect their code and not surface it to customers. I imagine some do open source these days, but many don't.

However, one of the [conditions of a vendor offering their app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/useragreement) on AppExchange is to provide "commercially reasonable support" to customers.

Reading into your question a bit, if there is something further you feel you need to know about how an AppExchange package is working, you should contact the provider. This information is always on the provider's page. In the instance of Email to Case Premium, you can [go here](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001R5cyEAC).

This is a popular app, so hopefully they will see it in their interest to offer you some assistance with whatever it is you need to know about that package.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.I have approached the team ,their have assisted me on other cases and it got resolved,But now im facing another issue ,i approached the team once again ,but their responded that their cannot assist because we do have only limited cases to raise .If their want to assist us we need get renewed the app .We do have requirement where we have written a trigger it works 90% of my requirement and left with 10% to acheive it.So i can see few of the trigger names  on the case object.So i do have a doubt whether any recursion is gng on when the trigger gets fired.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to view code in a managed package, it is akin to 'compiled' code on other platforms. The only way to view the code would be to see the source code in the Developer org from which the code was developed and packaged/released.

Note the following excerpt from [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging) link:

> Managed packages **provide intellectual property protection** (the source
>   code of many components is not available, in contrast to unmanaged
>   packages), as well as a way for the package creator to offer upgrades
>   to the package.